# Manage optional dynamic segment of URL in Flask with class based view

Tags: python, flask

I want to reproduce the behavior of having multiple URL linked to one endpoint while using Flask class based views.
Using classic Flask views I would do :

```
@app.route("/users")
@app.route("/users/<int:id>", defaults={"id": None})
def users(id):
    # Function
```

But how to reproduce this behavior with class based view using app.add_url_rule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, after you defined your class based view, just `add_url_rule` rules of each route, taking the example mentioned in [Flask's Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/views/#method-views-for-apis):

```
class UserAPI(MethodView):

    def get(self, user_id):
        if user_id is None:
            # return a list of users
            pass
        else:
            # expose a single user
            pass

    def post(self):
        # create a new user
        pass

    def delete(self, user_id):
        # delete a single user
        pass

    def put(self, user_id):
        # update a single user
        pass
```

Then you can add your routes as:

```
user_view = UserAPI.as_view('user_api')
app.add_url_rule('/users/', defaults={'user_id': None},
                 view_func=user_view, methods=['GET',])
app.add_url_rule('/users/', view_func=user_view, methods=['POST',])
app.add_url_rule('/users/<int:user_id>', view_func=user_view,
                 methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
```